# Why doesn't working LastEvaluatedKey on the DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using DynamoDB to store some additional info but it's not working on the order
I stored data like seed based on my JSON file
But it seems like an irregular position about the ID
I set the partition key to ID
But on the DynamoDB has arranged irregular ID
[image]
So I cannot do any control like pagination according to the LastEvaluatedKey
How can I fix the issue?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Right now your question is not answerable. What is a irregular ID, what are you trying to achieve, what have you tried and what isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

You want to get a list of items sorted by the ID property. You set ID property to be the partition key. You do not have a sort key. You state that the items returned are not sorted by ID.

This implies you are performing a scan operation. Scan operations do not guarantee the result will be in a sorted order. To get items in a sorted order you must define a sort key for the table and perform a query operation.

If you create a new table and define the partition key as 'item_type' and the sort key as 'ID', you will be able to run a query and return all items of a specified 'item_type' sorted by 'ID'.